# unable to build opendaylight project in maven

Tags: maven, ubuntu, opendaylight

Anyone tried to configure opendaylight maven environment in ubuntu??? following steps in the url https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_Controller:MD-SAL:Startup_Project_Archetype.... I'm not able to complete the steps, stopped with "Peer Not Authenticated" error while trying to build the project. I tried to install certificates using installCert java and keytool etc... it is not working at all... is there any other way out there to build this project or any environment to run a yang program? please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: Add some more info on your question. Don't use just links they may become offline and you question will make no sense. Try running it in debug mode and add the output here.

Comment: ERROR Could not transfer artifact org.opendaylight.odlparent:karaf-parent:pom:1.7.2-Boron-SR2 from/to opendaylight-mirror (https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/): peer not authenticated at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:159)

Comment: Are you behind some kind of proxy?

Comment: No proxy added to the server,

Comment: The problem is that this artifact `org.opendaylight.odlparent:karaf-parent:pom:1.7.2-Boron-SR2` doesn't exists on this repository. You have to find another source. See it [here](https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/org/opendaylight/) You can not find any odlparent nor karaf-parent artifact

Answer (score 0):

Hope you've added repository in your maven settings.xml. Once added please maven sure while running its taking your settings.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

    <profiles>

        <profile>
            <id>downloadSources</id>
            <properties>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>opendaylight-release</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>opendaylight-mirror</id>
                    <name>opendaylight-mirror</name>
                    <url>http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>opendaylight-mirror</id>
                    <name>opendaylight-mirror</name>
                    <url>http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>opendaylight-snapshots</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>opendaylight-snapshot</id>
                    <name>opendaylight-snapshot</name>
                    <url>http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>opendaylight-snapshot</id>
                    <name>opendaylight-snapshot</name>
                    <url>http://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>maven-central-repo</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>cetral-repo</id>
                    <name>maven-central-repo</name>
                    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>cetral-repo</id>
                    <name>maven-central-repo</name>
                    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <activeProfiles>
        <!-- <activeProfile>maven-central-repo</activeProfile> -->
        <activeProfile>opendaylight-release</activeProfile>
        <activeProfile>opendaylight-snapshots</activeProfile>
        <activeProfile>downloadSources</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```